# Bootstrap Dynamically Appended Button Group Not De-Selecting Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When I have a [Bootstrap 5 button group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/), the code looks as follows:

```html
<div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-between m-4">
  <input id="a" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="a">Option A</label>
  <input id="b" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="b">Option B</label>
  <input id="c" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="c">Option C</label>
</div>
```

This works fine if the group is on the page during pageload. However, if I dynamically append the elements after pageload, the buttons stay "active" once clicked and don't toggle properly.

```js
let options = ["D", "E", "F"];

let group = document.createElement('div');
group.className = 'btn-group d-flex justify-content-between m-4';
for (let type of options) {
  let button = document.createElement('input');
  button.id = type;
  button.name = type;
  button.type = 'radio';
  button.className = 'btn-check';
  button.autocomplete = 'off';
  group.append(button);
  let label = document.createElement('label');
  label.htmlFor = type;
  label.className = 'btn btn-outline-primary';
  label.innerHTML = 'Option ' + type;
  group.append(label);
}
document.body.append(group);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="m-4">On Pageload</h1>
  <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-between m-4">
    <input id="a" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="a">Option A</label>
    <input id="b" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="b">Option B</label>
    <input id="c" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="c">Option C</label>
  </div>
  <h1 class="m-4">Dynamically Appended</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the dynamically added buttons to share a name attribute.

If you notice in your onload group they all have the same name attribute: `name="btnradio"`

Whereas in your dynamically added group, they all have different name attributes:  `button.name = type;`
[image: screenshot showing that each button has same name as id]

Since they all have different names, they're seen as different button groups, so selecting another won't deselect the others.